# Do I need to Install a virtual machine to use PowerShell on Mac?

Tags: macos, powershell, virtual-machine, vmware

I am taking a PowerShell class at school, but I am using a Mac. Is there any way I can use PowerShell without downloading a virtual machine?

Comment: [Installing PowerShell on macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-macos?view=powershell-7).

Comment: For OSX no, PowerShell v7 is cross-platform. if you are saying you want to run Windows PowerShell on OSX, then yes you need a Windows VM. PSv7 cannot do all that Windows PowerShell (PSv5x and earlier) can do, and there are things you can do in Windows PowerShell you can't do in PSv7, and vice versa. They are two different deliveries, though on Windows you can run both side by side.